# как передать значения из JS в PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование, html5

кнопка вызывает функцию myFunction, она посылает гет запрос с данными в opportunities.php , а он печатает строку в новом окне.

как сделать так что бы opportunities.php  остался отдельным файлом, а результат его выполнения был не на новой странице, а добавился на основной (html)

```
onclick = "myFunction()" > Подобрать < /button>

  <
  script >
  function myFunction() {
    var v1 = (document.getElementById("type").value);
    var v2 = (document.getElementById("country").value);
    var v3 = (document.getElementById("newdate").value);
    window.location.href = "opportunities.php?type=" + v1 + "& country=" + v2 + "& newdate=" + v3;
  } <
  /script>

<?php
$type =$_GET['type'];
$country =$_GET['country'];
$newdate =$_GET['newdate'];
echo "home_mcs=" . $country . "&type=" . $type . "&earliest_start_date=" . $newdate . "&sort=%2Bcreated"
?>
```

Comment: погуглите в сторону AJAX. Думаю он поможет Вам решить данную задачу.

Comment: С помощью `XMLHttpRequest` и `FormData`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отправить данные в php нужно выполнить Http запрос, для этого в javascript существует объект `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
function myFunction() {
    var v1 = (document.getElementById("type").value);
    var v2 = (document.getElementById("country").value);
    var v3 = (document.getElementById("newdate").value);

    var params = 'type=' + encodeURIComponent(v1) +
                 '&country=' + encodeURIComponent(v2) +
                 '&newdate=' + encodeURIComponent(v3);

   // Создаём объект XMLHttpRequest
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   // Инициализация запроса
   xhr.open("GET", '/opportunities.php, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   // Инициализация обработчика события 
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       // здесь код js который выполнится по завершению запроса
   };

   // послать запрос
   xhr.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'opportunities.php',
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json или что-то ещё',
  data: {
    type: значение,
    ...
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // в data будет выводится то что выдаст скрипт в формате dataType
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Человек не упоминал о Jquery. И если у него не подключена библиотека, работать конструкция $.ajax не будет